# Simulate key being held down in C and WINAPI

Tags: c, winapi, keypress

I'm working on a project where I took a Super Nintendo controller, driving it with an Arduino. The Arduino reads the button presses on the controller, and sends it over a serial connection.

I'm working on a receiver program, which will read from the serial port, and then simulate key presses in Windows, so I can use the controller in other programs.

The thing is, I got pretty much everything down. Except there is one issue.
My simulated keypresses aren't actually being held down.

Here is the code for the A button (buttons are active low, so they are 'false' when being pressed)

```
if(!(buttonState.state_word & B_A))
{
    /* If previous state is not pressed, and current is pressed, simulate a keypress */
    if(prevState.state_word & B_A)
        keybd_event(0x41, 0x41,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | 0,0);
}
else if(buttonState.state_word & B_A)
{
    /* If previous state is pressed, and current is not pressed, simulate a key release */
    if(!(prevState.state_word & B_A))
        keybd_event(0x41, 0x41,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);  
}
```

When I press A on the SNES controller, an A will appear in notepad, for example.
And when I hold the A button on the SNES controller, a single A will appear in notepad, but the terminal will print that the key is being held, like I programmed it to do.

When the button is first pressed from being unpressed, it simulates the keypress. When it's held down, no more calls to simulate a keypress are made. And then when the SNES button is released, the keypress is also released.

Since there is this time between the keydown and the keyup, why is there only a single letter being printed, and not as if the keyboard was being held down and printing repeatedly?

Comment: When does `prevState` get updated?

Comment: It sounds like you want the keys to be "typematic". I don't know whether that works with simulated keyboard events in Windows.

Comment: you not need maintain buttons state at all. when you got remote event (keydown or keyup) you need direct call `keybd_event` without any checks and conditions

Comment: With your logic, you only set keys upon pressing/releasing. Shouldn't it rather just be: `if(buttonState.state_word & B_A)
{
  keybd_event(0x41, 0x41,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY,0)
}
else
{
  keybd_event(0x41, 0x41,KEYEVENTF_EXTENDEDKEY | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP,0);
}`?

I don't understand why you need to check the previous state. Any signal debouncing should be done in firmware and not by the PC.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to all who responded.

I ended up taking a different approach, using SendInput instead this time, and now it works like a charm.

As for the reason while I keep state, the way I saw it was if the button is being held down, I don't want to simulate another keypress each time the controller is polled. So I keep state, such that, if the button is pressed, and next time it is polled it is still being pressed, I won't generate another keypress. It will only be generated when the last state of the controller showed it wasn't pressed.

```
while(1)
{
    prevState = buttonState;
    ReadFile(   hCOM,
                &buttonState.state_word,
                2,
                &bytesRead,
                NULL);

    for(i = 0; i < 12; i++)
    {
        if(!(buttonState.state_word & (1 << i)))
        {
            /* If previous state is not pressed, and current is pressed, simulate a keypress */
            if(prevState.state_word & (1 << i))
            {
                in[i].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE;
                SendInput(1,&in[i],sizeof(INPUT));
            }
        }
        else if(buttonState.state_word & (1 << i))
        {
            /* If previous state is pressed, and current is not pressed, simulate a key release */
            if(!(prevState.state_word & (1 << i)))
            {
                in[i].ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_SCANCODE | KEYEVENTF_KEYUP;
                SendInput(1,&in[i],sizeof(INPUT));
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: This sounds like a hobbyist project, but if you want to turn it professional you should swap out ReadFile() for ReadFileEx() and use Windows "asynchronous I/O". Which in turn means that the thread won't consume 100% CPU like your current program does.

Comment: @Lundin: Doesn't synchronous I/O already solve the problem you created by going asynchronous?

Comment: @IInspectable What do you mean?

Comment: @Lundin: A blocking (synchronous) `ReadFile` call doesn't burn CPU cycles, while sitting there, waiting for data to arrive. The program, as posted, doesn't consume 100% CPU as you suggest (or whichever fractional part, given a multi-core setup). It'll only wake up, when there are 2 or more bytes to read from `hCOM`. If there isn't, the thread is suspended.

Comment: @IInspectable That depends on how you have configured COMMTIMEOUTS. Sure, if there is no time-out it will just hang there and not consume CPU. But then it will instead block the thread from doing anything meaningful.

Comment: @Lundin: Since you were contrasting `ReadFile` with *"asynchronous I/O"*, I assumed a `COMMTIMEOUTS` initialization, that results in a blocking wait. And if you read the question carefully, the fact that this thread cannot do anything meaningful (other than reading input, and producing output from it) is its designated design goal. Your feedback might be more helpful, where the problem is a different one.